# Is it possible to use BasicStrokes join types on a GeneralPath?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I have a polygon I've made with GeneralPath, and I've made a basic stroke with line thickness of 8 and set the join type to JOIN_MITER. When I try to paint this shape like so:

```
g2d.setStroke(stroke);
g2d.draw(generalPath);
```

It paints the shape with the correct line thickness, but it treats each line like it's own, giving it whatever type of cap end I define in the stroke. CAP_ROUND looks the best like this, but I would much prefer the if lines properly joined with JOIN_MITER. Can this be done? Am I using the right class when I use GeneralPath? Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

For context, here's the class stripped down to just the pertinent info. the paintComponent method is called from the paintComponent method of the JPanel which I'm drawing on, it has an arrayList of these which it iterates through and calls each their paintComponent methods at a time:

```
public class RShape extends RComponent{
    GeneralPath linkedLines;
    Stroke stroke;
    public RShape(int x, int y, int sides, Stroke stroke, int defaultLineLength) {
        this.stroke = stroke;
        linkedLines = new GeneralPath();
        double angle = ((double)360)/sides;//find what the angles would need to be to make a shape with that many sides
        double dStartX = x;
        double dStartY = y;
        double nextAngle;
        for(int i=0;i<sides;i++) {
            nextAngle = angle*i;
            nextAngle = nextAngle * Math.PI / 180;//convert to radians
            double dEndX = dStartX + defaultLineLength * Math.sin(nextAngle);//find where the end of the line should be for the given angle and line length
            double dEndY = dStartY + defaultLineLength * Math.cos(nextAngle);
            int endX = (int) Math.round(dEndX);//round to the nearest int
            int endY = (int) Math.round(dEndY);
            int startX = (int) Math.round(dStartX);
            int startY = (int) Math.round(dStartY);
            linkedLines.moveTo(startX, startY);//add the next segment of the GeneralPath
            linkedLines.lineTo(endX, endY);
            dStartX = dEndX;//move the starting point to the end point so it's ready for the next loop
            dStartY = dEndY;
        }
        linkedLines.closePath();//close the last gap.
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setStroke(stroke);
        g2d.draw(linkedLines);
    }
}
```

This is called like this:

```
ComponentList components = new ArrayList<RComponent>();
components.add(new RShape(50,50,5,new BasicStroke(8,BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER),60));
```

Comment: Can you provide more of a runnable example?

Comment: I've started using Polygon and Polyline instead. It solves my problem, but doesn't necessarily answer the question, so I don't know if I should post it as an answer.